# How To Parts Of Speech Only One Time In PHP

Tags: php

I want to show only one time the heading of parts of speeches for example when user enter the word  `"Spell"` all the parts of speeches and its meaning come every time .
The headings are repeating multiple times . i want to print only one time
[image]
There should be a heading Of Noun,Verb,Adjective etc..

like this

Noun.
Verb.
adjective.

[image]

this is my code

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    echo "<div id='wordid' style='display:none'>".$row["wordid"]."</div>";
 echo $count++." :  ".$row['definition']. "  ";

                    if($row['pos']=="n"){
                        echo "(Noun) <br/>";
                    }

                    if($row['pos']=="s"){
                        echo "(Subject) <br/>";
                    }

                    if($row['pos']=="p"){
                        echo "(Proverb) <br/>";
                    }

                    if($row['pos']=="a"){
                        echo "(Adjective) <br/>";
                    }

                        if($row['pos']=="v"){
                        echo "(Verb) <br/>";
                    }



}
```

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Instead use `mysqli` or PDO.

Comment: Having trouble understand exactly what you're aiming for. Can you post an example of your current output, and your desired output?

Comment: the headings are repeating multiple times like this i am attaching a screenshot i donot want to repeat the headings multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of what the last `wordid` was and only echo the header if it changed.

```
// initialize to avoid notices
$lastWordId = '';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  if ($lastWordId != $row['wordid']) {
    echo "<div id='wordid' style='display:none'>".
      $row["wordid"].
     "</div>";
    $lastWordId = $row['wordid'];
  }
  echo $count++." :  ".$row['definition']. "  ";

  if($row['pos']=="n"){
    echo "(Noun) <br/>";
  }

  if($row['pos']=="s"){
    echo "(Subject) <br/>";
  }

  if($row['pos']=="p"){
    echo "(Proverb) <br/>";
  }

 if($row['pos']=="a"){
    echo "(Adjective) <br/>";
  }

  if($row['pos']=="v"){
    echo "(Verb) <br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: @modgeek see edit. Not sure if I'm using $count as you intended